# Backwards propagation of errors in Python

Tags: python, neural-network, backpropagation

[image]

I'm trying to understand how backward propagation of errors works, so I'm trying to do this with the very simple neural network shown above.

I've done the following so far:

```
import numpy as np

def forward_propagation(X, theta_1, theta_2):
    z2 = np.dot(X, theta_1)
    a2 = sigmoid(z2)
    z3 = np.dot(a2, theta_2)
    y  = sigmoid(z3)
    return y

def sigmoid(z):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-z))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_layer  = 1
    hidden_layer = 1
    output_layer = 1

    # theta_1 = np.random.randn(input_layer, hidden_layer)
    # theta_2 = np.random.randn(hidden_layer, output_layer)

    theta_1 = np.array(([0.2]))
    theta_2 = np.array(([0.1]))

    X = np.array(([-5]), dtype=float)
    predicted_y = forward_propagation(X, theta_1, theta_2)
    print predicted_y
    Y = np.array(([1]), dtype=float)
```

with output:

```
 [ 0.50672313]
```

so now I have the activation of Y, but I don't understand at all how I can do backwards propagation and update the parameters `theta_1` and `theta_2`. I've been trying to follow along with [this video](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/lecture/du981/backpropagation-intuition), but I don't understand it at all. Other videos I have found seem to also do backwards propagation of errors differently, and so it's just making me more confused.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by trying to understand gradient descent in details and to probably calculate it for a simpler task, such as logistic regression or any other gradient-based least-squares task, by pen and paper. With neural networks, it's also very important to understand the chain rule of differentiation.

If you get this properly, you could start applying it to the neural network. It will clear things up a lot.